# How to stop a carousel sliding when reaches the last item?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm making a carousel from scratch, it contains 7 itens, the problem is when reaches the last item i still can click to the next one, i want that every time it reaches the last item it stops.

I'm using transform to make the sliding effect, so every time i press the next button it increases the translateX, i dont know if this is the better aproach.

```
 transform: ${({ currentSlide }) =>
    currentSlide ? `translateX(-${currentSlide}00%)` : "translate(0%)"};
```

I dont want this big space when I reach the last item

[image]

This should be the expected result when the last dog appears

[image]

Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/dogs-carousel-u7126?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

I'd modify how `currentSlide` is handled.  With 3 images on screen and 7 total in the carousel, advancing `currentSlide` past the 5th image is what causes the empty space, so preventing it from doing that by clamping `currentSlide` should fix the issue:

```js
// hopefully self-explanatory constants:
const NUM_IMAGES_VISIBLE = 3;
const NUM_IMAGES_TOTAL = 7;

// after sliding, try this, assuming currentSlide 0 is the first image:
currentSlide = Math.min( currentSlide, NUM_IMAGES_TOTAL - NUM_IMAGES_VISIBLE )
```

Comment: i dont get it, can you apply this solution on codesandbox? I dont know where to put the result from Math.min

Comment: @jarwin Oops, deleted something while editing.  Is it more obvious now? I'll see if I can make this work in codesandbox—but don't count on it, I have no experience with react.

Comment: not quite sure if this solution works, but if you can show me in codesandbox would be great

Comment: @jarwin As I suspected things weren't entirely plug-and-play. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/dogs-carousel-forked-9qx2h?file=/src/App.tsx) is your fixed carousel.  Also, I defined some constants up at the top—make sure you understand what they do!

Comment: Hmm but he problem is when i resize the page, mobile for example i cant pass to the next item